# How to tell relay to update a dataset?

Tags: reactjs, relay

**TL;DR:**
After reading through various resources about React and Relay and by building a prototype app with react-relay, I came across a problem that I cannot solve without help. It's about how to tell a mutation which data to save.

I have a component that shows details of a `User` entity. It's loaded via a relay query. This component has an `<input />` field with the name of the user and a save button that triggers a `relay.commitUpdate(...)` call. Whenever I change the name of the user in the input field and click on save, I can see that not the changed but the original name is send to the backend.

---

I am building an app with `react-relay` and I am working on a component that should display details about a `user` entity with the possibility to change these data and save it. It`s the detail part of the [Master-Detail-Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/master-details).

Loading and changing of data works fine. But changes are not commited to the backend. For data updates I am trying to use relay mutations.

After clicking on save, I can see in the developer console in my chrome browser, that unaltered data is send to my backend. What do I miss? Here is what I have so far (Typescript code).

(Update: when placing break points into the `onSaveClick()` method of the component and the `getVariables()` method in the mutation, I see that in `onSaveClick` the property `this.props.user` contains made changes while `this.props.user` in `getVariables()` returns the initial data.)

```js
export interface IUserDetailsProps { user: User }
export interface IUserDetailsStates { user: User }

class UserDetails extends React.Component<IUserDetailsProps, IUserDetailsStates> {
  constructor(props: IUserDetailsProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { user: this.props.user };
  }
  
  public onFirstNameChange(event: any) {
    let user = this.state.user;
    this.state.user.firstName = event.target.value;
    this.props.user.firstName = event.target.value; // is this needed?
    this.setState({ user: user });
  }
  
  public onSaveClick() {
    this.props.relay.commitUpdate(new UserMutation({ user: this.props.user }));
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    let user: User = this.props.user;
    return <div>
        <input type="text" value={user.firstName} onChange={this.onFirstNameChange.bind(this)} />
        <button onClick={this.onSaveClick}>Save</button>
      </div>;
  }
}

class UserMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
    public getMutation() {
        return Relay.QL`mutation {saveUser}`;
    }

    public getVariables() {
        return this.props.user;
    }

    public getFatQuery() {
        return Relay.QL`
            fragment on UserPayload {
                user {
                    id,
                    firstName
                }
            }
        `;
    }

    public getConfigs() {
        return [{
            type: "FIELDS_CHANGE",
            fieldIDs: {
                user: this.props.user.id
            }
        }];
    }

    static fragments = {
        user: () => Relay.QL`
            fragment on User {
                id,
                firstName
            }
        `
    }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(UserDetails, {
    fragments: {
        user: () => Relay.QL`
            fragment on User {
                id,
                firstName,
                ${UserMutation.getFragment("user")}
            }
        `
    }
});
```

---

Solution attempt:

I changed the line for the input field of the user's first name to this:

```
<input type="text"
    ref={(ref) => {
        this.myTextBox = ref;
        ref.value = this.props.user.firstName;
}} />
```

and removed the change event handler and removed all `state` code.

My click handler now looks like this:

```
public onSaveClick() {
    let user = Object.assign({}, this.props.user);
    user.firstName = this.myTextBox.value;
    this.props.relay.commitUpdate(new UserMutation({user: user}));
}
```

and I can see, that the user object passed to the mutation now has the new value for `firstName` that I have changed in the text input. But again, relay sends the unchanged `user` to my backend. Here is a screenshot that shows my problem:

[image: unaltered user is send to the backend]

Comment: In React, you shouldn't modify a components' `props`. Also, you should update the component's state using [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) function. You should avoid assignment to `this.state.user.firstName` and `this.props.user.firstName` in `onFirstNameChange` function.

Comment: `setState()` function allows us to provide a callback. Instead of having a change listener which gets invoked each time the name is changed, you can retrieve the modified name in `onSaveClick` function, call `setState()` with the new name and in the callback of `setState()`, invoke the mutation with updated state `this.state.user`;

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. But when I omit the onChange handler, my text input is like a read-only field because the component is not rerendered. I am using it now like this: `<input type="text" value={user.firstName} />`. How can I reflect changes in the view now? Could you give some example code in an answer?

Comment: You can use the [React ref callback attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) for the input text box. That way, you can retrieve the input text box's value in `onSaveClick` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help again. I was able to use the ref callback  attribute on the text input, but my problem is that actually the data passed to the mutation is not considered when relay makes a request to my backend. I attached a screenshot and solution attempt to my answer. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Could you extract the text input using ref in `onSaveClick` function?

Comment: Yes, `this.myTextBox.value` in the `onSaveClick` method is equal to what I typed into the text input. I call `new UserMutation()` with a  parameter `user` that contains made changes, but the payload of the backend request sends the original data. See my edited answer and the appended "Solution attempt" section.